# what is the number shown under one's name during chat?

Tags: support, reputation

During chat, if someone posts comments multiple times, we see an expanded info of the user containing his/her name and a value beneath.

At first I thought it must be reputation.But during an discussion,I found that it is not true.

In chat the value was **2724** while the users rep was at the time **175**.
So what is that number?

<sup>should I add images of the user rep?I thought it better not to post the images.please comment if I should put images.</sup>

Comment: I believe its the total rep combined from all of StackExcahnge sites the user is a member of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number shown under one's name during chat, is the total rep (global) combined from all of StackExcahnge sites the user is a member of.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108258/chat-shows-global-se-reputation-instead-of-site-rep) is the link to MSO that confirms this for sure.  MSO is the mother of all metas and lets us know what is going on stack wide.  If it's something stack-wide (like chat) this is the definitive source.  Something specific to a particular site gets more attention on the individual site meta.