# How is the reputation score one can see in chat calculated?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

My question is simple: You all know that in chat, one can see a reputation score of users below their icon and username (if they posted enough so that there is enough space) or by clicking on the icon to open the info bubble and hovering over the name.

However, this reputation score differs from the score on the parent site!

Which other scores are computed into it additionally?
And how are the scores between the 3 chat servers (chat.stackexchange, chat.stackoverflow, chat.meta.stackexchange) related?

Comment: Read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108260) and [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8543/184942)

Comment: @RegisteredUser There is nothing I would not know already. I know that this is the combined reputation score of some sites, but _which_ sites? Only those from one chat-mothersite (SE/SO/MSE), only those with at least a minimum rep (with or without +100 association bonus),...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253048/280862) it is the total combination of all the SE sites which you have 200+ rep on. And then the site specific chat for the StackOverflow site is just the rep that you have on StackOverflow. And the one for SE Meta is also site specific so it is just your rep on SE Meta.

Also, the 100 extra that you get on sites once you have reached 200 on one site is also counted.